# Creating menu for NSSegmentedControl using XIB

Tags: macos, cocoa

How do we create menu for a particular segment using xib for NSSegmentedControl ?

Answer (score 1):

You just drag an NSMenu from the object library and release it over the segment you want it to be attached to.

Comment: Have you tried this? I couldn't drag and release. It was not accepting the NSMenu.

Comment: Yes I did, and it worked fine.  Are you sure you're dragging a menu, and not a menu item?

Comment: Yes. Its NSMenu. If you are able to then how do you specify for which segment item, menu should be displayed?

Comment: It attaches to the segment you drop it on. Are you still not able to get it to work?  What version of Xcode and OS X are you using?

Comment: I am not able to drag and drop. I mean its not accepting the NSMenu drop. OS -> 10.7.3 XCode -> 4.2.1

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. When you drag the menu over the segment, you don't get the green "+"?  I'm using the same version of OS X and Xcode 4.2, so I think it should be the same. Have you modified the segmented control in any way after you dragged it into your window?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10108/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-sach)